# Mysql view data from two different table

Tags: mysql, sql

table A

```
|-------------|
|mohonID |nama|
---------------
|1111    |xxx |
|2222    |yyy |
--------------
```

Table B

```
|-------------|
|mohonID |nama|
---------------
|1111    |xxx |
---------------
```

result

```
|-------------|
|mohonID |nama|
---------------
|2222    |yyy |
--------------
```

That is my example table. how i want to view data from table A that table B no have data. Example table that i want to view is table RESULT. using mysql statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

```
select tablea.*
from tablea a
left join tableb b
  on a.mohonID=b.mohonID and a.nama=b.nama
where b.mohonID is null
```

and here is another

```
select tablea.*
from tablea a
where not exists(
  select * 
  from tableb b 
  where a.mohonID=b.mohonID and a.nama=b.nama)
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not support the EXCEPT operator, but you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE mohonID NOT IN(SELECT mohonID FROM TableB)
```